# HubConnection.Headers ... Missing SignalR in Client side

Tags: c#, signalr, blazor-webassembly

I need to add a token to a HubConnection headers as showed here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization

But C# intellisense has no Headers property. I use Blazor webassembly .Net core 3.0.
How to add Headers to an instance HubConnection in the client side?

Comment: I think you are looking at the wrong version of SignalR.  There are two versions that are very different.  One is for .NET Framework and the other for .NET Core.  You need Core.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved myy problem:

```
connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl("http://.../MyHub", 
                    (HttpConnectionOptions options) => options.Headers.Add("Bearer", token))
                .WithAutomaticReconnect() // closed after four attempts
                .Build();
```

Comment: you'll eventually run into a refresh token problem so it's easier to use: options.AccessTokenProvider

Comment: If the expiration date is in the token, you can check it and get a new token before using.  I do this with C# client and JS client.